# Will hadoop(sqoop) load oracle faster than SQL loader?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, apache-spark, data-warehouse, sqoop

We presently load  CDRs to an oracle warehouse  using a combination of bash shell scripts and SQL loader with multiple threads. We are hoping to offload this process to hadoop because we envisage that the increase in data due to increase in subscriber base will soon max out the current system. And we also want to  gradually introduce hadoop into our data warehouse environment.

Will loading from hadoop be faster? 
If so what's is the best set of hadoop tool for this?

Further info:
 We usually will get contunoius stream of pipe delimited text files through ftp to a folder, add two more fields to each record, load to temp tables in oracle and run a procedure to load to final table. How would u advice the process flow to be in terms of tools to use. For example;

- files are ftp to the Linux file system (or is possible to ftp straight to hadoop?) and flume loads to hadoop.
- fields are added (what will be best to do this? Pig, hive, spark or any other recommendations)
- files are then loaded to oracle using sqoop
- the final procedure is called(can sqoop make an oracle procedure call? If not what tool will be best to execute  procedure and help control the whole process ?)

  Also how can one control the level of paralleism ? Does it equate the number of mappers running the job?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar task of exporting data from a < 6 node Hadoop cluster to an Oracle Datewarehouse.
I've tested the following:

- Sqoop
- [OraOop](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors/sqoop/oracle/v1-6.html)
- [Oracle Loader for Hadoop](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/bdc/hadoop-loader/overview/index.html) from the "Oracle BigData Connectors" suite
- Hadoop streaming job which uses sqloader as mapper, in its configuration you can read from stdin using: `load data infile "-"`

Considering just speed, the Hadoop streaming job with sqloader as a mapper was the fastest way to transfer the data, but you have to install sqloader on each machine of your cluster. It was more of a personal curiosity, I would not recommend using this way to export data, the logging capabilities are limited, and should have a bigger impact on your datawarehouse performance.

The winner was Sqoop, it is pretty reliable, it's the import/export tool of the Hadoop ecosystem and was second fastest solution, according to my tests.(1.5x slower than first place)

Sqoop with OraOop (last updated 2012) was slower than the latest version of Sqoop, and requires extra configuration on the cluster.

Finally the worst time was obtained using Oracle's BigData Connectors, if you have a big cluster(>100 machines) than it should not be as bad as the time I obtained. The export was done in two steps. First step involves reprocessing the output and converting it to an Oracle Format that plays nice with the Datawarehouse. The second step was transfering the result to the Datawarehouse. This approach is better if you have allot of processing power, and you would not  impact the Datawarehouse's performace as much as the other solutions.

Comment: Thanks Teodor. It nice to know that sqoop excels ...   I read that oraOop was added to the latest sqoop. I have added more info. Kindly advice.

Comment: @Oxax and Teodor. Would you mind providing some information or resources about the architecture you used to achieve this especially on Hadoop streaming job ? We are planning to build something similar but dont really know where to start

Comment: This was an old answer. I haven't worked with Oracle since but I would have a look at Spark and how to write from Spark to Oracle. I am not sure if there is a special connector for Spark that allows high speed writes. (faster than jdbc).